Comparing slopes with contrasts with the marginaleffects package
I am trying to learn a bit about the similarities and differences between how emmeans and {marginaleffects} packages work. The documentation from Arel-Bundock and Heiss are great, but for some reason I am stuck on something that I am sure is obvious. I'll give the example using the palmerpenguins data:
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)
library(emmeans)
library(palmerpenguins)


To simplify things I am considering only the Chinstrap and Gentoo species. I build a model to see how body mass varies as a function of sex, species, and flipper length. Suppose I am interested in exploring the sex-by-flipper length interaction more closely. In particular, I'd like to use both packages to find the slopes of body mass on flipper length for both sexes, averaged across species.
My model:

penguins_b <- penguins %>%
  filter(!is.na(sex)) %>% 
  filter(species != "Adelie")

mod1 <- lm(body_mass_g ~ sex*species*flipper_length_mm, 
           data = penguins_b)


With emtrends I can find both slopes and the test of their contrast:
emtrends(mod1, var = "flipper_length_mm", pairwise ~ sex )


females: 23.6, males: 29.3, contrast p.value = 0.4866

However, I am stuck as to how to perform the test using the marginaleffects package. I can find the slopes (which presumably are different from emtrends because of the different ways the packages average, correct?). And I have been able to compare adjusted means in body mass. But for some reason, I have not found a way in the documentation to compare the slopes, as I did above with emtrends. I am either overlooking something obvious, or failing to understand something.
avg_slopes(mod1, variables = "flipper_length_mm", by = "sex")


females: 26.6, males: 26.1


My primary question is whether there is a way to test that same contrast in the marginaleffects package, and if so, how?

While I'm asking, though, am I correct that this difference in slopes is due to the different averaging methods the packages used, as described in the documentation by Vincent Arel-Bundock and Andrew Heiss?


Thanks!

This should in my view be rewritten to focus on a statistical question. Questions primarily about code to use are off-topic here. Easier to fix, as I have done: it's a good idea to tag the software you're using.

The difference between emmeans and marginaleffects in this case is not the average. The difference is the “grid” on which slopes are first computed before average.
By default, emmeans builds a “balanced” grid, where each row represents one of the possible combinations of values categorical values, with numeric predictors held at their means.
datagrid(model = mod1, grid_type = "balanced")
>      sex   species flipper_length_mm rowid
> 1 female Chinstrap               209     1
> 2 female    Gentoo               209     2
> 3   male Chinstrap               209     3
> 4   male    Gentoo               209     4

Then, emmeans computes slopes, evaluated at each point of that grid, and takes the average within each sex group.
In contrast, the default marginaleffects strategy is to compute slopes for every row of the original data, and only then to take averages by sex group. You can change this default using the newdata argument. Then, you can compare the group-wise means using the hypothesis argument.
I know that emmeans has some “cell weight” argument which can be used to do something similar to what marginaleffects does by default. However, I’m not sure how to use it or if it applies here. Therefore, the code below only shows how to replicate emmeans with marginaleffects, and not the other way around:
emtrends(mod1, var = "flipper_length_mm", pairwise ~ sex )
> NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
> $emtrends
>  sex    flipper_length_mm.trend   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
>  female                    23.6 6.28 179     11.2     36.0
>  male                      29.3 5.10 179     19.2     39.3
> 
> Results are averaged over the levels of: species 
> Confidence level used: 0.95 
> 
> $contrasts
>  contrast      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
>  female - male    -5.64 8.09 179  -0.697  0.4866
> 
> Results are averaged over the levels of: species

avg_slopes(mod1, 
    variables = "flipper_length_mm",
    newdata = "balanced",
    by = "sex")
> 
>               Term    Contrast    sex Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)    S
>  flipper_length_mm mean(dY/dX) female     23.6       6.28 3.76   <0.001 12.5
>  flipper_length_mm mean(dY/dX) male       29.3       5.10 5.73   <0.001 26.6
>  2.5 % 97.5 %
>   11.3   35.9
>   19.3   39.3
> 
> Columns: term, contrast, sex, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted 
> Type:  response

avg_slopes(mod1, 
    variables = "flipper_length_mm",
    newdata = "balanced",
    by = "sex",
    hypothesis = "pairwise")
> 
>           Term Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
>  female - male    -5.64       8.09 -0.697    0.486 1.0 -21.5   10.2
> 
> Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
> Type:  response


Thank you very much Vincent!

@AndrewStoehr If this answers your question, you can select it as the answer and/or upvote it. This expresses gratitude and helps future searchers hone in on the best solutions by looking at answered questions with many upvotes.

Thanks Dimitri. I selected it as the answer. I can't seem to upvote because I apparently don't have the reputation yet.
